# Delphi Sorting Single-Linked List

Tags: delphi, pascal, bubble-sort

I need bubble-sort singly-linked list.
Here's code where I trying to do that.
So it gets in infinity loop and does not work.
I am trying to bubble sort singly-linked list.

```
  procedure Sort;
 var  
     temp :char;
     curr :node;
   didSwap :boolean;
 begin
   didSwap := true;
   while (didSwap = true) do begin
       didSwap := false;
     curr := head;
       while (curr^.next <> nil) do begin
           if (curr^.value > curr^.next^.value) then begin
               temp := curr^.value;
               curr^.value := curr^.next^.value;
               curr^.next^.value := temp;
               didSwap := true;
               curr := curr^.next;
           end; 
       end;
   end;
 end;
```

Comment: This is a great opportunity for you to learn to use the debugger. Set a breakpoint at the top of your procedure and run. When the breakpoint is hit, step through the code one line at a time to see where the logic is failing.

Comment: This is going to be very inefficient. Presumably this is a homework assignment?

Comment: FYI:  for linked list it is simpler to implement selection sort

Comment: KenWhite well it ends with empty list. Good job debugger in delphi. *shrugs*
DavidHeffernan, yes I can not wait getting to a better language like Python or C++ as homeworks. Delphi is just meh.
MBo well let me take a look on realization of it, after all it is about soring out singly-linked list, not double-linked one.

Comment: @KenWhite it fails:
       while (curr^.next <> nil) do begin
           if (curr^.value > curr^.next^.value) then begin
               temp := curr^.value;
               curr^.value := curr^.next^.value;
               curr^.next^.value := temp;
               didSwap := true;
               curr := curr^.next;
           end; 
       end;

Comment: What *fails*? What does *fails* mean? What do you see happening in the code that you've quoted in your comment (and that is already in your question)? You've provided several lines of code and said it *fails*, but not explained which line is the problem or what *fails* means. The point of using the debugger is to step through the code and watch the value of variables in order to see why the logic is not working as expected.

Answer (score 1):

```
  procedure Sort;
  var  
      temp :char;
      curr :node;
    didSwap :boolean;
  begin
    didSwap := true;
    while (didSwap = true) do begin
        didSwap := false;
      curr := head;
        while (curr^.next <> nil) do begin
            if (curr^.value > curr^.next^.value) then begin
                temp := curr^.value;
                curr^.value := curr^.next^.value;
                curr^.next^.value := temp;
                didSwap := true;
            end; 
                curr := curr^.next;
        end;
    end;
  end;
```

Sadly I found wrong place for increment.
curr := curr^.next;

Comment: Bubble sort leaves the last item sorted after each pass. Each loop iteration should visit one fewer list entry.